# Should there be a new tag "legacy-bios"?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'd like to propose the creation of the tag "legacy-bios", as I believe it was relevant to a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151397/unable-to-access-grub-in-win10-ubuntu18-04-legacy-dual-boot) I just asked. It seems like it could be relevant to a forum dedicated to an OS. And there is already a "uefi"-tag.

Comment: There is [tag:csm], maybe this could become a synonym. [tag:bios] exists too, but is not exactly supposed to be the same topic, I think. Probably used as such though, would have to look into it more deeply.

Comment: I prefer CSM over Legacy BIOS.

Comment: We already have a [tag:bios] tag, why do we need a new one?

Comment: Would it be useful to add something like "This is not about EFI systems" to the excerpt of [tag:bios] and/or shall we create a synonym "legacy-bios". There is this widespread confusion about what is what.